# Cannot see the document in the CouchBase database

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using the couch base community edition, I am facing a strange problem where I cannot able to see my inserted document. I have tried to retrieve the data using: swagger, couch base query console but, I could not able to view the data.

Can anyone suggest me what can be the issue here.

Its not happening with all the document only with 1 specific document.

Comment: How did you insert the document? If you go to the Admin Console, and then the Buckets tab, and click on Documents, do you see the document in the list?

Comment: Please post a sample of your code so this problem can be narrowed down.

Comment: @JohanLarson i inserted the code using my backed code which is in spring boot and used swagger api for that

Comment: @MatthewGroves what code you want its simple rest api POST request, and the strange thing is i am not putting any expiry time so that my document should expiry automatically .